# article about number of connected users?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Several months (maybe even a year or two) ago, I saw an asp .net article that showed how to tell how many people were connected to a running web application. Of course I only glanced over the article & didn't save it. Does anyone remember seeing the article or know where I can find it or perhaps something like it? I have searched Google from the best of my memory of the title & content but I'm getting no hits.

The reason I'm asking is because I have a WCF web service that has crashed several times after I publish updates and the only thing I can think that would cause these weird problems is that people are connected to it & its corrupting the files. I'm not going to publish any more updates during the day now, but we also have a couple of people that work during the night and it would be nice to see if people are connected or not before "flipping the switch".

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks,

Wali

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following article shows how you can use **Session`_`Start** and **Session`_`End** of the **Global Application Class** to count the number of active sessions:

[How to show number of online users / visitors for ASP.NET website?](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-show-number-of-online-users-visitors-for-ASP-NET-website.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your search, consider using keywords like

> perfmon asp.net sessions

Intel has a good article. Unfortunately, it's 404 at the moment, but [Google cache has a nice copy](http://74.125.95.132/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENCA324&=&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsoftware.intel.com%2Fen-us%2Fblogs%2F2008%2F04%2F03%2Fusing-perfmon-to-tune-n-tier-net-applications%2F&btnG=Google+Search&meta=lr%3D&aq=f&oq=). Original link to the [Intel "Using perfmon to tune n-tier .NET applications"](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/04/03/using-perfmon-to-tune-n-tier-net-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

When your WCF service crashes, there are likely to be entries in the Windows event log. If not, then the service should be doing logging on its own. I suggest you look and find out whether the service may not have been telling you wnat's wrong.